# Laravel Query Builder Nested Join and Alias

Tags: mysql, laravel, query-builder

How to create this query using Laravel's Query Builder:

```
SELECT `content`.`tagable_id`,`taged`.`tag_id`
FROM `taged`
RIGHT JOIN
    (SELECT `taged`.`tagable_id`,`taged`.`tag_id`
    FROM `taged`
    WHERE `taged`.`mask_flag`='0'
        AND `taged`.`tagable_type`='App\\\Post'
        AND `taged`.`user_id`='1') AS `content`
ON `taged`.`mask_flag`='1'
    AND `content`.`tagable_id`=`taged`.`tagable_id`
    AND `taged`.`tagable_type`='App\\\Post'
    AND `taged`.`user_id`='1'
```

The parenthesis around the inner `SELECT taged.tagable_id...` is where my main problem lies.

Comment: I have been trying it and haven't been able to get it to work yet. It produces a number of errors. Thank you though.

Comment: What are those errors?  Try moving the `WHERE` conditions out of the join function as I have updated below

Answer (score 2):

Here is your Laravel query:

```
$result = DB::table('taged')
             ->select('content.tagable_id', 'taged.tag_id')
             ->rightJoin(DB::raw('SELECT tagable_id, tag_id FROM taged AS content'), function($join)
         {
             $join->on('taged.mask_flag', '=', 1);
             $join->on('content.tagable_id', '=', 'taged.tagable_id');
             $join->on('taged.tagable_type', '=', 'App\\\Post');
             $join->on('taged.user_id', '=', 1);
         })
         ->where('content.mask_flag', '=', 0);
         ->where('content.tagable_type', '=', 'App\\\Post');
         ->where('content.user_id', '=', 1);
         ->get();
```